# Background art for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am currently making background art for an android game I am making. I am wondering what is the best way to support multiple screen sizes. 
It's currently 1920x1080 for drawing purposes but this can be changed. Should I change the size before I put it in my game? And how can I implement it so it won't be stretched or squashed on different screens?
I'm only asking about the background as most other things are coded relative to the size of the screen.
Thanks, oli.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I am using libgdx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create different resources (with different resolution) for different screen sizes as they are grouped by the dpi. 
Take a look [here](http://coh.io/adpi/)

Comment: Thanks, how do I avoid it looking odd on screens with different aspect ratios?

Comment: Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

You can specify long and notlong for resources.
long: Long screens, such as WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA
notlong: Not long screens, such as QVGA, HVGA, and VG